# Isn't external ORM as overcomplicated as EJB?

Tags: orm

How external ORMs simplify anything when you have to cope with complex XML configuration like the Java EJBs ? Complexity just hide somewhere else. Moreover It introduces dependencies on External 3rd parties above the dependencie to Microsoft. So where's the advantage ?

Comment: EJBs? By Microsoft? In your dreams (or perhaps, nightmares)

Comment: Where's the dependency on Microsoft coming from if you are using Java and Hibernate?  ORM and XML are not related.  Modern Java is becoming increasingly driven by annotations, so earlier dependency on XML was an implementation detail, nothing more.

Comment: @Vinay I know EJB is for Java J2EE :) But it doesn't matter if it is Java or .NET

@stevendick I don't see much difference between XML and Annotation: annotation will act as code generator to create the XML so from the viewpoint of architecture it doesn't change the complexity level ?

Comment: I'm unaware of any tool or library related to Java ORM that generates XML from annotations.  Even if it did, so what?  Another implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

With which ORMs are you dealing with complex XML?  That is hardly "normal" for ORMs and it's generally not the only option.

A good ORM simplifies your life significantly, it doesn't make it more complicated.

You don't have to take a dependence on any library you are willing to code yourself.  They are called reusable components for a reason.

Go ahead and start from scratch or use one of the inadequate ORMs from Microsoft (since it seems as though you've accepted that dependency), it sounds like you have plenty of time to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If it was so simple then why Martin Fowler says it's too complicated :)
http://www.infoq.com/presentations/domain-specific-languages

Comment: I'm not watching a 25 minute video.  If you have a specific part to point out, let me know.  DSLs are different from ORMs, so I'm not sure why DSLs would be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

An ORM is trying to solve the mistmatch between the way a database works,stores and returns information and the way we want our code to work, store data and manipulate that same data.

This is not a solved problem and the tools are changing and improving. Every decision in this area usually involves a trade off and in order to balance the design tradeoffs you do have to understand more of the history of what problems each ORM is trying to solve before writing it off as too complex.

At the end of the day, an ORM is there so you can use code instead of writing it from scratch.

For more on this type of discussion, check this [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/06/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science.html) post.